# Return the element of a list at which the function's return value is the highest

Tags: haskell, max

I have to write an `Ord c => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a` function that returns the value at which the first function parameter returns the highest value.

For example:

> ownMax (\x -> x `mod` 5) [7,8,9] == 9
>
> ownMax length ["words", "are", "hard"] == "words"

So far, I have the following code where I tried to use the `maximumBy` function as it can be used to get similar results as to what I want to achieve.

```
ownMax :: Ord c => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
ownMax f (x:xs) = maximumBy((\a b -> compare (f a) (f b)) (x:xs))
```

Right now, it can't be loaded because of a `Couldn't match type ‘Ordering’ with ‘a -> Ordering’` error.

Comment: There is a problem with the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the parenthesis. You open two parenthesis for the `maximumBy` and this means you apply `(x:xs)` as parameter for the lambda expression you defined. You can define the lambda expression as first parameter and the list `xs` as second with:

```
ownMax :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
ownMax f xs = maximumBy (\a b -> compare (f a) (f b)) xs
```

You can also work with [**`on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on)  to apply a function on both parameters, so:

```
import Data.Function(on)

ownMax :: (Foldable t, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> t a -> a
ownMax f = maximumBy (compare `on` f)
```

or even shorter:

```
import Data.Function(on)

ownMax :: (Foldable t, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> t a -> a
ownMax = maximumBy . on compare
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Ord c`  in the first line of code  get replaced by `Ord b` as it doesn't seem that type variable c plays any useful role ?

Comment: @jpmarinier: yes, that was a copy-paste error.